# Error using bcdedit when setting up hypervisorlaunchtype

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, bcdedit

I need to get virtual machine running. (I have windows 8 pro, hypervisor feature installed and checked virtualization settings in BIOS). I see hypervisor is not running message when I try to start a new VM.  After bit of searching, I was instructed to set hypervisorlaunchtype to Auto.

When I tried to setup using bcdedit,
I got the following error :

```
The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.
```

Bit of history - I have windows 8 on dell inspiron 3520. I migrated my SATA HD to SSD (Disk copied using EZGigIV). I am using SSD as primary disk. I have no issues in booting.

I tried `bootrec /rebuildallbcd`. I got the following error :

```
A device attached to the system is not functioning
```

Please advice how to fix this problem.

Comment: which bcdedit command have you use?

Comment: never know there are multiple bcdedit. I used the one in system32 and in recovery console

Comment: I mean the command line. What have you entered into the cmd?

Comment: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

Comment: this should be the correct command: **bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto**

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9f12f4e0-e2b7-4163-acc3-8cacb8a8997c/windows-7-backup-error-0x800703ee) and especially the last two entries relating to recreating the BCD. Ensure first that your backups are in good shape and that you have a boot DVD or USB for Windows.

Comment: I was already able to boot. I just cannot set hypervisorlaunchtype

Comment: Have you run bcdedit using "Run an administrator" ?

Comment: Yes. I tried even from recovery console

Comment: @Lokeshwer - Any luck resolving/ getting around?

Comment: Nope. I reached to MS tech support. No solution provided. I had to rebuild from scratch